# How to find accuracy in multi-GPU Tensorflow training?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

When we do training in Tensorflow multi-GPU environment, how do we find test accuracy and display them in terminal next to the training loss?
1. Can we find test accuracy on single GPU?
2. Should we find test accuracy on all available GPUs and then calculate the average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to average the accuracies on all GPUs and that will give you the overall accuracy. Suppose you have 64 exemplars on each of 4 GPUs for a batch size of 256 (= 4 * 64 ). If 50,48,56,52 are accurately labeled in each of them respectively, then your overall accuracy is 50 + 48 + 56 + 52 = 206 / 256 = 80.47%.

Sometimes, when you want to calculate something more complicated than accuracy, you might suppose that the result from one GPU is a good approximation of the overall value and save yourself the trouble of getting all the values from all GPUs. For that to be valid, there are two conditions that have to be satisfied:

1. The batch should be randomly assigned to each GPU, normally they are shuffled for that purpose.
2. The batch should be large enough for each GPU to receive at least 32 exemplars.